# Grep all strings that start and end with the same substring

Tags: bash, command-line, grep

I need to grep all lines that start and end with the same substring of at least 4 letters. The substrings can't overlap.

So imagine we have the input:

```
ABCDOOOPABCD
BBBBOLPOKBBBB
ACLMDJKAC
12345---12345
ABCD
```

Then the output should be:

```
ABCDOOOPABCD
BBBBBOLPOKBBBBB
12345---12345
```

Comment: Should whitespace be ignored or not? For instance, should this string match: ' ABCXXXXABC '?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using `grep` with a basic regular expression:

```bash
grep -x '\(.\{4,\}\).*\1' file
```

Using `grep` with an extended regular expression (`-E`):

```bash
grep -Ex '(.{4,}).*\1' file
```

Using `-x` option for only full line matches.

An explanation for the regular expression:

- `(.{4,})` A group of at least 4 characters
- `.*` From 0 to an infinite numbers of characters
- `\1` A backreference to the first captured group (in this case `(.{4,})`)